# Discussion about proxy- and instrument variables and endogeneity in the context of a multi equation model

Tags: regression, correlation, estimation, structural-equation-modeling, instrumental-variables

Assume two equations

1. $Y_1 = X_1\beta_1 + X_2\beta_2 + U_1$
2. $Y_2 = X_1\alpha_1 + X_2\alpha_2 + U_2$

Further assume that $ \ U_1 = X_4 + E_1$ and $U_2 = X_4 + E_2$

with $ \ corr(Y_1,X_4)\ne 0, \ \ corr(Y_1,E_2)= 0 \ \ \ $ and $ \ \ \ corr(Y_2,X_4)\ne 0, \ \ corr(Y_2,E_1)= 0$

So if we would estimate eq. 1 and 2 by OLS we would get a omitted-variable-bias-problem since the regressor $X_4$ does not appear in either equation.

**My question is:** Since $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ do not appear in those equations as explanatory variables, i.e. are not correlated with each other, then could one use $Y_1$ as a proxy for $X_4$ in eq. 2 and analogously $Y_2$ as a proxy for $X_4$ in eq. 1? My answer would be, yes if one controls for the potential endogenity of those variables since the two requirements for a proxy variable are given

1. the proxy variable is correlated with the unobservable variable
2. the proxy variable is not partially correlated with the dependend
   variable

---

Secondly assume the two equations

1. $Y_1 = Y_2\beta_1 + X_1\beta_2 + X_2\beta_3 + U_1$
2. $Y_2 = Y_1\alpha_1 + X_1\alpha_2 + X_2\alpha_3 + U_2$

Further assume that $ \ U_1 = X_4 + E_1$ and $U_2 = X_4 + E_2$

with $ \ corr(Y_1,X_4)\ne 0, \ \ corr(Y_1,E_2)= 0 \ \ \ $ and $ \ \ \ corr(Y_2,X_4)\ne 0, \ \ corr(Y_2,E_1)= 0$

So if we would estimate eq. 1 and 2 by OLS we would get a omitted-variable-bias-problem paired with a endogenity-problem since the regressor $X_4$ does not appear in either equation and the dependend variables $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are jointly determined within the model.

**My question is:** For instance: The endogenity of $Y_2$ in eq. 1 is due to

1. the partial correlation to $Y_1$
2. the partial correlation to the omitted regressor $X_4$

If I would use a control function approach which controls for this endogenity of $Y_2$ in eq. 1 dont I get a quantitiy which not only controls (1) but also for (2)? In my opinion this does not yield a solution for a omitted-variable-bias-problem but yield a solution for the endogenity?

**So bottom line:** If $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are actually not correlated I would actually be able to solve the omitted-variables-bias-problem. In any case I need to justify which of my problems is more serious in order to find a adequat solution.

Comment: Without going into more details, in dealing with such type of questions it helps a lot if the model of the problem is stated clearly. I.e. first state the model, the theoretical relationships and the parameters of interest. Then think of the estimation strategy. Now your initial assumption is ambiguous. Either the equations have the $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ or they haven't.

Comment: If your initial model is without $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ and $X_2$ and $X_3$ do not correlate with $X_4$, you can estimate $\alpha_2,\alpha_3$ and $\beta_2,\beta_3$ consistently. Then simply use $Y_2-\hat\alpha_2X_1-\hat\alpha_3X_2$ as an estimate for $X_4$ in the first equation, it will have an error $U_2$, but  since it does not correlate with $Y_1$ this is not a problem.

Comment: I edited my main post to get a better grasp on my intentions behind my question.

Comment: $Y_1$ and $X_4$ will be correlated no matter what, as $X_4$ is a part of $U_1$, and $U_1$ is, in turn, a part of $Y_1$. So I don't see the importance of stating these correlations.

Comment: @StasK I just edited my post. Due to the comments from mpiktas I noticed that I was not a 100% sure what goal I actually wanted to achieve.

Comment: If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are not correlated with $X_4$ and $U_1,U_2$ you do not have omited variable bias problem. The OLS estimates of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are consistent, but not efficient in this case.

Comment: Indeed. I wrote down this rather abstract model because my empirical example is a bit more complicated. Since I devide between endo- and exogenous regressors the assumption is already pretty strong regarding a potential correlation to the omitted variable. In my study $X_4$ resembels smth. like IQ. This is probably the case some of my endogenous variables correlate. In each equation I've two endogenous variables. Between those I can observe multicolinearity. This is the reason I'm convinced that the connection of both variables to the depended variable is determined by IQ. By that I would

Comment: observe the second case of my previous post in which the endogenous variables act as proxy variables for IQ. My guess is that if I choose to control for the endogenity I can observe the connection between the endogenous explanatory variable and the omitted variable.

Comment: Is this train of thought comprehensible?